# Why do people outside academia generally have PhDs?

Tags: phd

I see that some people working outside academia have PhDs.

Why do people outside academia generally have PhDs?

1. Do they first do PhD, fail to find job in the academia, and then join industry?
2. Do they join industry and then see that a PhD is needed for career development and then do a PhD?
3. Both #1 and #2?
4. Any other reason?

Comment: All of the above, plus: 1. They decided during the PhD that they want to go to industry, 2. They took a PhD before joining industry, in the assumption that the PhD would increase their chances for a good position in industry (applies only to a few fields).

Comment: point 1. of @lighthousekeeper comment could be extended to people who decide they want to go to industry during a later career stage.

Comment: Also, let's acknowledge the possibility that some people think studying for a PhD will be an interesting experience in itself, unrelated to any subsequent career plans.

Comment: In the US: once upon a time, AT&T Bell Labs, IBM Research, GE Research, and other large companies had large R&D labs with lots of PhDs. Google and Microsoft employ many PhDs now, as do companies like Intel, Micron, and others. And then there is the entire DOE National Labs complex, employing thousands and thousands of PhDs engaged in research. If your view is that only academia values (and hires) PhDs, you should look around. Field dependent, but in STEM there are lots of jobs for PhDs in lots of places.

Comment: And don't forget all the pharmacology and biomedical companies...

Comment: In some places, having a PhD is viewed positively for politics (though sometimes these PhDs are questionable)

Answer (score 5):

It is probably a mistake to think of those people as failures. I know several such people and all are extremely well qualified - and very productive and successful.

I'd guess that in the case of my friends and colleagues, they were simply offered interesting and lucrative positions when they were about to graduate and took them. Some of them do/did pretty much what I did (retired now) except for teaching. Lots of speaking, lots of travel, lots of deep thinking. They also earned just about twice what I did at similar career points.

I think it was Bill Joy who once called three of them "The Crown Jewels of Sun Microsystems" for their technical contributions to Java and other things.

However, at the current moment, jobs in academia are hard to find and both of your points certainly do happen.

Comment: It isn't "probably" a mistake - it is most definitively and unambiguously a mistake. There are many jobs requiring a PhD outside of academia.

Answer (score 3):

I personally earned a PhD because I knew I wanted to be research scientist for a federal conservation agency.
Furthermore, I picked my graduate program because most of their alumni do not work as professors, something they proudly list on their [website](https://www.entx.ttu.edu/tiehh-alumni.html).

Here are some *Any other reason?* that are similar to those shared by [Buffy in another answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/201484/33210):

- We knew our dream jobs required a PhD.
- We like doing research, but not teaching.
- We like having a work-life balance (in my case, 40 hours a week).
- We dislike the all-too-common petty academic politics and egos of academia (these problems exist outside of academia, but often are not as bad).
- We have jobs that require specialize training only PhD programs provide.

Additionally, many (perhaps surprising to many people both inside and outside of the academy) have jobs that require specialized training that requires a PhD, especially for higher responsibility and pay positions.
Examples include:

- Clinical phycologists who treat more advanced cases.
- Biostatisticians who lead the teams/research groups.
- "Researcher scientists" and similar roles who need to understand how to conduct research and conduct research. These jobs are in the private sector and public sector (e.g., government agencies).
- Medical entomologists with the [U.S. Navy](https://www.navy.com/careers/entomology) require a graduate degree and I known several PhDs who have worked there as well as one or two MS-degree holders. The PhDs start off with higher rank. I'm not sure about their other benefits of their PhD.

For the skills, my friend who is a biostatistician noted to me once that one PhD (e.g., four years of post-undergrad study) is not the same as 2 masters (e.g., two two-year degrees).
The PhD generally have deeper skills and better problem-solving skills.

Lastly, the tone of your question's multiple-choice reasons implies people, such as me, are failures for not obtaining a tenure track or other job in "academia".
Please think about this if you ever apply for a non-academic position.

Answer (score 3):

I personally started a PhD knowing I would not stay in academia afterwards, because the academic job market is insane (I did not even look).

Why do a PhD then?

- The knowledge gained is directly useful to my job.
- It might also enable a career transition.
- I wanted to prove to myself that I'm smart enough to do a PhD.

You could also look at why employers hire PhDs (there are plenty of job advertisements that specifically require a PhD). I asked one employer that question. The industry was technical, but not related to academics. He said he tried hiring someone with a BSc for the position once, and he found he had to tell the person exactly what to do. Comparatively, he could describe the goal in general terms to a PhD, and expect the PhD to fill in the blanks.

Comment: If your field were mathematics, I'd say a good answer would be "Well, its mathematics."

Comment: That PhD cf BSc argument was also told to me as BSc cf HnD...